# Regex to match any string that donot contain special charecters or blank spaces but can either one . or _ , but not at the begining or last

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex to match any string that do not contain special characters but can contain either one `.` or `_` and this should not be in the beginning or at the end of the string. I also want to keep the length of the string between 8 and 20 characters. The regex I am using now is the following:

```
"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z._]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
```

I haven't got much expertise with regex. So is there any way I can get a solution for my issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z](?!(?:.*?[._]){2})[._a-zA-Z0-9]{6,18}[0-9a-zA-Z]$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM7wS3/2)

**Regex Breakup:**

```
^                   # match start of input
[0-9a-zA-Z]         # match a digit or letter
(?!(?:.*?[._]){2})  # negative lookahead to disallow use of _ or . more than once
[._a-zA-Z0-9]{6,18} # match a digit or letter or dot or _ 6 to 18 times
[0-9a-zA-Z]         # match a digit or letter
$                   # match end of input
```

**PS:** Using `{6,18}` in the middle part to make total length on string between 8 and 20.

Comment: thanks, but the problem here is it allows both . or _ at a time. I am trying to match a string where it can contain none of the special characters, or one . or one _ but not both together and not more than once

Comment: I am trying to validate a form, in ftl